# Is it natural to say "xxx sports contain a, b, ..."

Tags: word-usage

According to Cambridge Dictionary, ["include"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/include) means

> to contain something as a part of something else, or to make something part of something else

while "[contain](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/contain)" means

> to have something inside or include something as a part

[According to an ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/58467)

> The distinction between 'includes' and 'contains' is a bit more subtle. 'Contains' is used when there is something else that is doing the containing. The box is a **container**, and contains the hats. You would not, generally, say that the box includes the hats. Inside the box is a set of objects, and that set (which 'contents' refers to) includes (and consists of) the hats.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combat_sport)

> Common combat sports **include** mixed martial arts, boxing ...

Is it still natural if I substitute "contain" for "include"?

> Common combat sports **contain** mixed martial arts, boxing ...

Answer (score 1):

“X contains Y” requires thinking of X as a *container*. Not all containers need to be physical, but I don’t think of “combat sports” as even a virtual container. They are using it to mean a *list* of sports and then give examples “included” in that list. Lists are not containers.

Answer (score 0):

“Includes” actually works much better. “Contains” almost makes it seem as if they are saying combat sports are a mixture of the different specific disciplines it mentions. “Includes” is more clearly showing that “combat sports” is a category and that boxing, wrestling, kick boxing, etc. are examples of sports in that category.

Comment: _Contains_ is definitely not appropriate, for the reason given in the quoted paragraph. The sports listed are not inside anything.